# compactness in $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Given a sequence of positive  numbers $\{c_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$. In $X=\ell^2$, let $M$ be a subset given by 
$$M=\{x=(x_1, x_2, \ldots) \in \ell^2: \ \ |x_i|\leq c_i, \mbox{ for all i }\}.$$
Prove that $M$ is compact if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n^2 < +\infty$.

Comment: No.$\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: It has been edited! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\sum c_i^2=+\infty$, then the elements
$$
x_k=(c_1,c_2,\dots,c_k, 0\dots)
$$
are in $M$, $x_k\in M$. The sequence $(x_k)$ is unbounded in $l^2$ as well as each subsequence, and $M$ cannot be compact.

That answers one half of your question.

Comment: You prove the same implication twice.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Deleted one of them.

Answer (score 2):

A metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Theorems)).

So you need to show that $M$ is complete and totally bounded if and only if $\sum_n |c_n|^2$ is finite.

Comment: In case $\sum c_n^2=+\infty$, how to show $M$ is not compact.

Comment: You can't because it may not be true.